# How high is one billion pennies stack on top of eachother? A penny is about 1/16 or .0625 of an inch thick.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

One Billion Pennies
A penny is 1/16 or .0625 of an inch thick
1,000,000,000 x .0625 = 62,500,000

It takes 16 pennies to make an inch stack
62,500,000 / 16 = 3,906,250 inches

So how many feet?
3,906,250 / 12 = 325,520.83

How many miles?
325,520.83 / 5280 = 61.65

So one billion pennies stacked is about 61.6 miles high.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 0.0625 and then dividing by 16? It seems like you're doing the same adjustment twice.

Comment: It takes $16$ pennies to make an inch stack, and you have $1\,000\,000\,000$ pennies (not just $62.5$ million pennies): $1\,000\,000\,000/16 = 62\,500\,000$ inches

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I am.

Comment: The first calculation accounts for the height of one billion pennies times .0625 equaling 62,500,000 pennies.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake... thanks! So I don't need the first calculation. Knowing that 16 pennies equal an inch then just divide 1billion by 16 to get 62,500,000 inches. And then to find out feet divide by 12 to get 5,208,333.33 feet. Finally to find miles divide that by 5280 to get over 986 miles! Thanks!

Comment: If you include units in your calculations, the first calculation would be

$$1\,000\,000\,000\text{ pennies} \times .0625\text{ inches/penny} = 62\,500\,000\text{ inches}$$

Comment: Excellent Thank you!

Comment: Without a calculator and hardly any arithmetic: $16$ pennies for an inch, $12$ inches for a foot, $5280$ feet for a mile, so $16\cdot 12\cdot 5280$ pennies for each mile. This is a little more than $15\cdot 12 \cdot 5000=15\cdot (12\cdot 5)(1000),$ which equals $15\cdot 60\cdot 10^3 = 15\cdot 6\cdot 10^4 = 90\cdot 10^4,$ which in turn is a little less than $100\cdot 10^4=10^6.$ Thus, there are about $10^6$ pennies for each mile, and thus $10^9$ pennies is about $\frac{10^9}{10^6} = 10^3=1000$ miles. The approximation likely good since the over and under estimates partially cancel each other.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro doing the factorization on the exact value gives you better control of the error: $16 \cdot 12 \cdot 5280 = 2^4\cdot 3\cdot 2^2 \cdot 2^5\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 = 2^{11} \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 11$. Since $2^{10}\approx 10^3$ with a 2.4% underestimate and $3^2\cdot 11 \approx 10^2$ with a 1% overestimate, the denominator becomes $10^6$ with a roughly 1.4% underestimate, so the value is $10^3$ miles with a 1.4% *over*estimate, i.e roughly $1000 - 14 = 986$ miles.

Comment: @NickD: Nice! Something I used to do in class a lot (mid 1990s to mid 2000s) was show without having to resort to much hand-calculation (much less a calculator) that (in theory; in practice is another matter) about 42 foldings of a sheet of paper produces a paper thickness that is about the distance to the Moon. An outline of the estimate is given in this [17 January 2008 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/Gi8r-RHtoVM/m/jvfUqPv7lHMJ), which incidentally includes some other things that oklord might be interested in seeing.

Comment: Too late to change, but it should have been *mid 1980s to mid 2000s* in my previous comment.